# why is a const array not accessible from a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

i have a constexpr function named access, and i want to access one element from an array:

```
char const*const foo="foo";
char const*const bar[10]={"bar"};

constexpr int access(char const* c) { return (foo == c); }     // this is working
constexpr int access(char const* c) { return (bar[0] == c); }  // this isn't
int access(char const* c) { return (bar[0] == c); }            // this is also working
```

i get the error:

```
error: the value of 'al' is not usable in a constant expression
```

why can't i access one of the elements from access? or better how do i do it, if it is even possible?

Comment: Does it work? or not?

Comment: @MikeSeymour ok I don't know C++ Should I delete comment?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan sorry, no it's not working. my approach is working without `constexpr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The array needs to be declared `constexpr`, not just `const`.

```
constexpr char const* bar[10]={"bar"};
```

Without that, the expression `bar[0]` performs an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion in order to dereference the array. This disqualifies it from being a constant expression, unless the array is `constexpr`, according to C++11 5.19/2, ninth bullet:

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>
> - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr

(and a couple of other exceptions which don't apply here).

Comment: Now the interesting question is, why does it work for the non-array version even if that is just `const` but not `constexpr`?

Comment: @us2012: I'm not sure of the exact rules; I think you can use `const` values (including pointers like `foo`), but not the results of expressions (like `bar[0]`) unless all the subexpressions are `constexpr`. Or something.

Comment: @us2012: I think I've found the relevant rule now.

Comment: So then how the array element is accessed - this is so hilarious.