# Are constexpr array members compile time constants?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the code fragment

```
struct Parameters {
   static constexpr int n = 2;
   static constexpr double v[n] = {4.0, 5.0};
};
```

legal C++11? And, if so, are `Parameters::v[0]` and `Parameters::v[1]` compile time constants or is just the pointer `Parameters::v` itself a `constexpr` (whatever that would mean at compile time)?

As you can see I am generally a bit confused about `constexpr` arrays and their initialization in classes/structs. Please feel free to not only answer my specific question but also to mention common pitfalls and the like concerning this topic.

Comment: Note that `v` is not a pointer, it's an array.

Comment: Seems to be perfectly legal: http://ideone.com/oMwXAj

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`x\[0\] == 1\` constant expression in C++11 when x is const int\[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903113/x0-1-constant-expression-in-c11-when-x-is-const-int)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ interesting, because my clang (3.4) won't link without also providing a def to provision the array (but has no problems with the integer constant). how odd. regardless, it still *compiles*, just puking on the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no problem with the construct. Quoting C++11, `[dcl.constexpr]`:

> §1 The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable, the declaration of a function or
>   function template, or the declaration of a static data member of a literal type (3.9). ...
>
> §9 A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have
>   literal type and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call shall be a constant
>   expression (5.19). Otherwise, or if a constexpr specifier is used in a reference declaration, every full-expression
>   that appears in its initializer shall be a constant expression. Each implicit conversion used in
>   converting the initializer expressions and each constructor call used for the initialization shall be one of those
>   allowed in a constant expression (5.19).

`double` is a literal type, and so is an array of literal types. Which means that `v[0]` and `v[1]` from your code are indeed constant expressions.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Parameters {
  static constexpr int n = 2;
  static constexpr double v[n] = {4.0, 5.0};
};

int main() {
  constexpr int a = Parameters::v[0];
  return 0;
}
```

This code on gcc 4.8.2 compiles into the following:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   c7 45 fc 04 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x4
   b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
  10:   5d                      pop    rbp
  11:   c3                      ret
```

So yes, it is a compile time constant.

clang 3.4 produces similar code:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
   9:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
  10:   c7 45 f8 04 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x4
  17:   5d                      pop    rbp
  18:   c3                      ret
```

Again, it is a compile time constant.

Everything was compiled with -O0.

P.S.: If a is declared const, then for gcc nothing changes but for clang does, the value 4 is not mov'ed directly as if was a compile time constant.

If a is declared neither const or constexpr then both compilers fail to treat Parameters::v[0] as a compile time constant.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Parameters {
   static constexpr int n = 2;
   static constexpr double v[n] = {4.0, 5.0};
};
```

This fragment by itself is certainly legal as far as I can tell. Section 7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr] of the C++11 standard says that

> The constexpr specifier shall be applied only to... the declaration of a static data member of a literal type

and a *literal type* is defined in 3.9:

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> — a scalar type; or...
>
> — an array of literal type

So `static constexpr double v[2] = { ... }` is certainly valid as far as I can tell.

As to whether the members of the array are `constexpr`... I'm not sure. If we declare

```
constexpr double d = Parameter::v[1];
```

then both g++ and clang compile it okay, but the clang version fails to link with an undefined reference to `Parameters::v`. I don't know whether this points to a Clang bug, or whether the construct is invalid.

Comment: Technically, I don't think the members of the array can be `constexpr`, as they're not complete objcets. But you cannot access them directly anyway, you can only acces them through the expression `Parameters::v[0]` (or `1`). And that satisifies all the requirements of a constant expression.

Comment: @Angew But from a practical point of view, the address of `Parameters::v` will be set by the linker or runtime, and not known to the compiler. So naively, `*(Parameters::v + 1)` as a `constexpr` would be a bit tricky?

Comment: `C++11[expr.const]§2,3` define the reuqirements on constant expressions, and the array dereference does not violate any of them. So it's a constant expression.