# Inconsistent warning "conversion from 'const unsigned char' to 'const float' requires a narrowing conversion"

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-c++, gcc-warning

Visual C++ 2017 and gcc 5.4 produce `conversion from 'const unsigned char' to 'const float' requires a narrowing conversion` warning for `Line B` but not for `Line A` in this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const unsigned char p = 13;
    const float         q = p;  // Line A

    std::cout << q << '\n';

    const unsigned char c[3] = {0, 1, 255};
    const float         f[3] = {c[2], c[0], c[1]};  // Line B

    for (auto x:f)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Is this warning valid? Why `Line B` is treated differently than `Line A`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is valid, from C++11 [narrowing conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) are prohibited in [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization); but not applied in [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) (as before).

> If the initializer clause is an expression, implicit conversions are allowed as per copy-initialization`, except if they are narrowing (as in list-initialization) (since C++11).`
>
> Until C++11, narrowing conversions were permitted in aggregate initialization, but they are no longer allowed.

And

> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
>   prohibiting the following:
>
> - conversion from an integer type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression whose value can be stored
>     exactly in the target type

BTW: `c[0]`, `c[1]` and `c[2]` are [not constant expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18903113/3309790); you might declare the array as `constexpr`, i.e. `constexpr unsigned char c[3] = {0, 1, 255};`. Then exception applied and [Line B](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fAWPkoYlfCIuoUvZ) would work fine too.

Comment: But the initializer list in my example consists exclusively of `constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type`!

Comment: @PaulJurczak AFAIK `c[0]`, `c[1]` and `c[2]` are not constant expressions.

Comment: @PaulJurczak See [`x[0] == 1` constant expression in C++11 when `x` is `const int[]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18903113/3309790).

Comment: Replacing `const` with `constexpr` removes the warning for gcc 5.4, but not for Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: @PaulJurczak I guess it's a VS issue; it's not standard-compliant in some ways.

Comment: One question still remains: prohibition of implicit conversion by language standard in this case is now clear to me, but the warning complains about `narrowing conversion`, which is not occuring here, unless it is about the general case of up to 64-bit `unsigned char` being converted into 32-bit `float`.

Comment: @PaulJurczak Interesting question. The standard just says before the checking of whether the value can be stored in `float`, the source must be a constant expression. It's hard to tell the principle behind.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Warnings do not make a compiler non-complaint. The reverse isn't true; when the Standard requires a diagnostic the compiler must emit at least a warning.

Comment: @MSalters I meant after replacing `const` with `constexpr` VS shouldn't give warnings.

Comment: @songyuanyao It shouldn't, but what MSalters is saying (AFAICS) is that this is a quality of implementation issue, not one of standard-compliance.

Comment: @ArneVogel But it's giving a (wrong) diagnostic on well-formed code; well, I can understand what you said.

Comment: @songyuanyao: A compiler could give the warning for using the letter E too much, and still be compliant. The Standard only requires that the compiler produces a correct binary for well-formed code.